# error: call of overloaded distance is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std, ambiguous

I have a bit of code (which I didn't write, but am trying to compile) -- [iostream_combo.cc](https://github.com/opencog/moses/blob/master/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.cc)--, and doing so gives me the following error:

> ```
> ./moses/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.cc: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string opencog::combo::l2ph(const string&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’:
> ./moses/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.cc:543:64: error: call of overloaded ‘distance(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::const_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&)’ is ambiguous
>              arity_t idx = distance(labels.begin(), found_it) + 1;
>                                                             ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
>              from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
>              from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:40,
>              from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
>              from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
>              from ./moses/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.h:28,
>              from ./moses/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.cc:24:
> /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: note: candidate: ‘typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type = long int]’
>  distance(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
>  ^~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/distance.hpp:18,
>              from /usr/local/include/boost/range/functions.hpp:21,
>              from /usr/local/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38,
>              from /usr/local/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:30,
>              from ./moses/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.h:30,
>              from ./moses/moses/comboreduct/combo/iostream_combo.cc:24:
> /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/distance.hpp:49:9: note: candidate: ‘constexpr typename boost::iterators::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type boost::iterators::distance_adl_barrier::distance(SinglePassIterator, SinglePassIterator) [with SinglePassIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::iterators::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type = long int]’
>      distance(SinglePassIterator first, SinglePassIterator last)
>      ^~~~~~~~
> ```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 x64, Boost 1.68 and gcc 8.2. So, the steps to reproduce the problem would be as follows:

1. On Ubuntu 16.04
2. install `gcc-8`
3. Use it to build boost 1.68 from source
4. Git clone the [moses repository](https://github.com/opencog/moses) sand follow the instructions from there: basically 1) git clone and build `cogutil`; 2) try to make `moses`:
   `cd build`, `cmake ..`, `make`.

I understand C++ enough (I think) that I can see that the call to `std::distance` is overloaded. What I don't see is the way to disambiguate it, although I guess it must include some re-writing of `found_it` or some explicit castings instead of `auto`.

Comment: Being a member for such long time, and with that many questions, you should know better. Where's the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Perhaps time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? And of course read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) as well.

Comment: Apologies, I considered the problem to depend on code and language only, not other specifics.

Comment: Explicit type declarations are not casts. `auto` deduces exact types deterministically, so there's no difference. C++ is always strong-typed

Comment: That file is 600+ lines long and requires multiple external dependencies. Please try to reproduce this into one, small program that is < 50 lines.

Comment: @Barry I thought the same, and then I did, by just confirming a hunch :)

Comment: should be fixed after https://github.com/opencog/moses/pull/93 .  surprised nobody mentioned reporting the bug upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls are like:

```
    arity_t idx = distance(labels.begin(), found_it) + 1;
```

This means that `distance` is found via ADL and hence all associated namespaces are considered. This might prove problematic if e.g. there are two namespaces providing an equally applicable overload for `distance`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee3a34b7bb3383b)</kbd>**

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace OyVeh {
    struct X { };

    template <typename It>
    size_t distance(It, It) { return 42; } // just to throw in a wrench
}

int main() {
    std::vector<OyVeh::X> v{3};

    auto f = v.begin();
    auto l = v.end();

    // now f and l have both `::std` and `::OyVeh` as associated namespaces. The following is ambiguous:

    return distance(f, l);
}
```

There are roughly 2 ways to fix it:

- remove the ambigious `distance` declaration from the associated namespace (this might not be possible if e.g. the ones competing are `std::distance` and `boost::distance`)
- edit the calls to remove the reliance on ADL (e.g. qualify them like `std::distance(...)` or parenthesize them `(distance)(...)`)

Showing the workarounds:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5458efd31fb2871)</kbd>**

```
{
    using OyVeh::distance;
    return (distance)(f, l); // parentheses suppress ADL
}

return std::distance(f, l); // also works, obviously
return OyVeh::distance(f, l); // but beware the meaning might change
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a common name for ADL, and this answer has prompted me to look into it.

Comment: It turns out that it was sufficient to just replace `distance` with `std::distance`. Which leaves me undecided about the answer -- should I mark it as a correct one?

Comment: Yes. Because it explains the cause and also the exact workaround you ended up using. Beware of the comment of course (though in this case it really seems obvious that the semantics of `std::distance` are desired)