# Any way to wrap construction of boost "tee" stream for automatic type deduction?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-iostreams

boost::iostreams::tee and company have a bit of a noisy/repetitive usage as seen here:

[C++ "hello world" Boost tee example program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999120/c-hello-world-boost-tee-example-program)

The goal is to make something like:

```
auto myTeeStream = make_tee(std::cout, myfile);
```

After trying to wrap this usage with a function make_tee to allow for automatic type deduction on the arguments I realized that both copy and move constructors are unavailable for the necessary types.

So: **is there a sane way to wrap tee stream creation in c++11**?

Here's my attempt that fails to compile because of deleted copy constructors and missing move constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

template <typename StreamT1, typename StreamT2>
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::tee_device<StreamT1, StreamT2> >
make_tee(StreamT1 & t1, StreamT2 & t2)
{
    using boost::iostreams::stream;
    using boost::iostreams::tee;
    return stream<decltype(tee(t1,t2))>(tee(t1,t2)); // compile error
    //return std::move(stream<decltype(tee(t1,t2))>(tee(t1,t2))); // also fails of course
}


int main()
{
    {
        // desired usage
        std::ofstream myFile("file.txt");
        auto && myTee = make_tee(std::cout, myFile); // required from here
    }
    {
        // noisy default usage
        std::ofstream myFile("file.txt");
        using boost::iostreams::tee;
        using boost::iostreams::stream;
        auto && myTee = stream<decltype(tee(std::cout, myFile))>(tee(std::cout, myFile));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error from `clang++ --std=c++11 teetest.cpp` is:

```
teetest.cpp:14:12: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::tee_device<basic_ostream<char>, basic_ofstream<char> > >'
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903903/c-copy-a-stream-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile fine in c++17 with *"guaranty copy elision"*.

In c++11, you might use `return {..}`:

```
template <typename StreamT1, typename StreamT2>
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::tee_device<StreamT1, StreamT2> >
make_tee(StreamT1 & t1, StreamT2 & t2)
{
    using boost::iostreams::stream;
    using boost::iostreams::tee;
    return {tee(t1,t2)};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0ef6fa9126b631d)

Comment: Yes! thank you. I was unaware that uniform initialization guaranteed no copy in C++11.

Comment: @Catskul It's not actually giving you `guaranteed RVO`.  It directly constructs the return value and then the lifetime of that temporary is being extended by capturing it by reference.

Comment: Given c++17 I'd strongly consider simplifying to `auto make_tee(T& t, U& u) { return boost::iostreams::tee(t, u); }` (there might be value in keeping the ADL on `tee()` but I'm not sure that was a conscious extension point. In fact it's prone to lead to [ambiguous scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52122093/85371))

Comment: @sehe: I tried to kept OP's code, but indeed, I'm not sure ADL is needed here.